# Clearing textbox makes it inaccessible

Tags: javascript, textbox, reset

See the atttached fiddle. I have a trial in which pressing buttons will place them into a textbox. I want users to be able to "start over" and hit the "clear" button to erase their answer. The clear button works, but afterwards, pressing other buttons does not put them back into the textbox as before.

Current code for "clear" button:

```
function CLEAR(){
letters.value = "";
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxPoLyGLoTxx/ea6rnwLr/

Comment: I don't understand why do you repeatedly use in your code the same `id` for different buttons, since `id` attribute must be unique. You can achieve the same result with html `class` attribute. You can see `id` details here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp

Comment: Good call. Thanks! I will probably switch that around to make it "class".

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
letters.clear = "";
```

with

```
letters.innerHTML = "";
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea6rnwLr/5/)

Comment: That is the simple and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function F() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "F");
}
function H() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "H");
}
function J() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "J");
}
function K() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "K");
}
function L() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "L");
}
function N() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "N");
}
function P() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "P");
}
function Q() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Q");
}
function R() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "R");
}
function S() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "S");
}
function T() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "T");
}
function Y() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Y");
}
function BLANK() {
  document.getElementById('letters').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', " ");
}
function CLEAR(){
  letters.innerHTML = "";
};
```

```css
html {
 background: white;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom: 0;
 right:0;
}
#wrapper{
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
#row1 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 10%;
}
#button1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: both;
}
#button3{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button5{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button6{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#row2 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
}
#row3 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
}
#row4 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 40%;
}
#finalrow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
}
#letters{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  color: red;
  width: 175px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<b><center>Select the letters in the order presented. Use the blank button to fill in forgotten items.</center></b>
<div id="row1">
<p>
<button onclick="F()" id="button1" value="F">F</button>
<button onclick="H()" id="button2" value="H">H</button>
<button onclick="J()" id="button3" value="J">J</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row2">
<p>
<button onclick="K()" id="button1" value="K">K</button>
<button onclick="L()" id="button2" value="L">L</button>
<button onclick="N()" id="button3" value="N">N</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row3">
<p>
<button onclick="P()" id="button1" value="P">P</button>
<button onclick="Q()" id="button2" value="Q">Q</button>
<button onclick="R()" id="button3" value="R">R</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row4">
<p>
<button onclick="S()" id="button1" value="S">S</button>
<button onclick="T()" id="button2" value="T">T</button>
<button onclick="Y()" id="button3" value="Y">Y</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="finalrow">
<p>
<button onclick="BLANK()" id="button4" value="BLANK">BLANK</button>
</p>
<p>
  <center><textarea id="letters" disabled></textarea></center>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="CLEAR()" id="button5" value="CLEAR">CLEAR</button>
</p>
<p>
<button type="submit" id="button6" value="SUBMIT">DONE</button>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lettersEle = document.getElementById('letters');

function setlettersValue(val) {
   lettersEle.innerHTML += val.value
}

function BLANK() {
  lettersEle.innerHTML = "";
}
function CLEAR(){
  letters.innerHTML = "";
};
```

```css
html {
 background: white;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom: 0;
 right:0;
}
#wrapper{
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
#row1 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 10%;
}
#button1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: both;
}
#button3{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button5{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#button6{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: top;
  clear: left;
}
#row2 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
}
#row3 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
}
#row4 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 40%;
}
#finalrow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 height: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
}
#letters{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  color: red;
  width: 175px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<b><center>Select the letters in the order presented. Use the blank button to fill in forgotten items.</center></b>
<div id="row1">
<p>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button1" value="F">F</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button2" value="H">H</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button3" value="J">J</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row2">
<p>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button1" value="K">K</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button2" value="L">L</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button3" value="N">N</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row3">
<p>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button1" value="P">P</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button2" value="Q">Q</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button3" value="R">R</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="row4">
<p>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button1" value="S">S</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button2" value="T">T</button>
<button onclick="setlettersValue(this)" id="button3" value="Y">Y</button>
</p>
</div>

<div id="finalrow">
<p>
<button onclick="BLANK()" id="button4" value="BLANK">BLANK</button>
</p>
<p>
  <center><textarea id="letters" disabled></textarea></center>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="CLEAR()" id="button5" value="CLEAR">CLEAR</button>
</p>
<p>
<button type="submit" id="button6" value="SUBMIT">DONE</button>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```